# How to convert object into div containing keys + values?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a function that'll take in and object and return the key and values in divs. For example, given the following object: `{id:"string",name:"string"}`, it should return the following:

```
<div>
 <div className="key">
  id
 </div>
 <div className="value">
 string
 </div>
 <div className="key">
 name
 </div>
 <div className ="value">
 string
 </div>
</div>
```

It could have any number of key/value pairs.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` with `map` like this:

```
Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => {
  return (
    <div key={key}>
      <div className="key">{key}</div>
      <div className="value">{value}</div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ES6 `Object.keys()` to solve this problem:

```
const data = { id: 'string', name: 'string' };

const MyFunction = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(data).map((key, i) => (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
          <div className='key'>{key}</div>
          <div className='value'>{data[key]}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```